# React Switch always going to first Route

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, router

Here if I am hitting "/" or "/reset_password" or any other route always first component in PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes  gets called i.e. PublicRoute with message ROUTE_CONSTANTS.RESET_PASSWORD

```
<Router>
         <Switch>
           <PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes />
           <PublicRoute key={1} redirect={false} path="/" component={CheckAuthenticatedRoutes} />
         </Switch>
     </Router>
```

```
const PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes = (props) => {
  return [
    <PublicRoute
      {...props}
      key={"/reset_password"}
      redirect={false}
      path={"/reset_password"}
      render={(routeProps) => <div>{ROUTE_CONSTANTS.RESET_PASSWORD}</div>}
    />,
  ];
};
```

```
const PublicRoute = (props) => {

  const { userAuthenticationDetails, redirect } = props;

  const isLoggedIn = (userAuthenticationDetails && userAuthenticationDetails.isLoggedIn) || false;
  if (isLoggedIn && redirect) {
    return <Redirect to={"/dashboard"} />;
  }
  return <Route {...props} />;
};

export default PublicRoute;
```

Comment: You should use the `exact` prop on the routes, otherwise it will just match the first that matches at all: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: @Jayce444 where and why should i put exact.Ideally If i am hitting lets say "/" then it should go to CheckAuthenticatedRoutes component but its going to PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes first element

Answer (score 0):

It's the `return` statement on your `PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes` component that's doing this.  You are returning an array of `PublicRoute` components.  React does not know how to render this properly.  Instead, you should return multiple routes as children of a `Switch` component.

It's fine to have multiple `Switch` statements in a `Router`.  All `Route` components need to be direct children of a `Switch` (unless you want to render multiple `Route`s).

You do need to figure some things out regarding your match conditions because the `Switch` at the top-level of the the `Router` means that traffic will go to either `PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes` OR `PublicRoute` - not both.  Currently all traffic gets handled by `PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes` so that `PublicRoute` component with `key={1}` is never shown.

```
const PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes = (props) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <PublicRoute
        {...props}
        key={"/reset_password"}
        redirect={false}
        path={"/reset_password"}
        render={(routeProps) => <div>{ROUTE_CONSTANTS.RESET_PASSWORD}</div>}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Note: you aren't currently calling `PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes` with any `props` when you use it in the `App` so you don't actually need to accept or pass down that `props` object if you don't want to.

Comment: i tried adding switch in PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes but still the main parent switch always going to first route i.e. PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes.Its doesnt checks that there is no route with that name so go to next route.Moreover If i pass path prop to PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes it works fine.But I can't have an array of paths as prop to PurelyUnauthenticatedRoutes.As it wont be right approach